# (NodeJS, large JSON file) | stream-json npm package error: Javascript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

stream-json noob here. I'm wondering why the below code is running out of memory.

## context

I have a large JSON file. The JSON file's structure is something like this:

```js
[
   {'id': 1, 'avg_rating': 2},
   {'id': 1, 'name': 'Apple'}
]
```

I want to modify it to be

```js
[
   {'id': 1, 'avg_rating': 2, 'name': 'Apple'}
]
```

In other words, I want to run a `reducer` function on each element of the values array of the JSON (`Object.values(data)`) to check if the **same** `id` is entered into different keys in the json, and if so "merge" that into one key.

The code I wrote to do this is:

```js
var chunk = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'},{'id': 1, 'avg_rating': 2}]

const result = Object.values(chunk.reduce((j, c) => {
      if (j[c.id]) {
        j[c.id]['avg_rating'] = c.avg_rating
      } else {
        j[c.id] = { ...c };
      }
      return j;
}, {}));

console.log(result)
```

The thing is, you cannot try to run this on a large JSON file without running out of memory. So, I need to use JSON streaming.

## the streaming code

Looking at the `stream-json` documentation, I think I need to use a `Parser` to take in text as a `Readable` stream of objects and output a stream of data items as `Writeable` buffer/text "things".

The code I can write to do that is:

```js
const {chain}  = require('stream-chain');
const {parser} = require('stream-json/Parser');
const {streamValues} = require('stream-json/streamers/StreamValues');
const fs = require('fs');

const pipeline = chain([
  fs.createReadStream('test.json'),
  parser(),
  streamValues(),
  data => {
    var chunk = data.value

 
    const result = Object.values(chunk.reduce((j, c) => {
          if (j[c.id]) {
            j[c.id]['avg_rating'] = c.avg_rating
          } else {
            j[c.id] = { ...c };
          }
          return j;
    }, {}));

    //console.log(result)

    return JSON.stringify(result);

  },
  fs.createWriteStream(fpath)

])
```

To create a write stream (since I do want an output `json` file), I just added to the parse function above `fs.createWriteStream(filepath)` , but it looks like -- while this works on a small sample -- this doesn't work for a large JSON file: I get the error "heap out of memory".

## attempts to fix

I think the main issue of the code is that "chunk" philosophy is wrong. If this works via "streaming" a JSON line by line (?), then "chunk" might be trying to save *all* the data that the program has run into so far, whereas I really only want it to run a reducer function in batches. I then am kind of back at square one .. how would I merge the key-value pairs of a JSON if the `id` is the same?

If the data custom code **isn't** the problem, then I get the feeling I need to use a [Stringer](https://github.com/uhop/stream-json/wiki/Stringer) , since I want to edit a stream with custom code, and save it back to a file.

However, I can't seem to get how `Stringer` reads data, as the below code runs an error where data is undefined:

```js
const pipeline = chain([
  fs.createReadStream('testjson'),
  parser(),
  data => {
    var chunk = data.value

    const result = Object.values(chunk.reduce((j, c) => {
          if (j[c.id]) {
            j[c.id]['avg_rating'] = c.avg_rating
          } else {
            j[c.id] = { ...c };
          }
          return j;
    }, {}));
    console.log(result)
    return JSON.stringify(result);
  },
  stringer(),
  zlib.Gzip(),
  fs.createWriteStream('edited.json.gz')
])
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice on this situation or any help diagnosing the problems in my approach.

Thank you!!

Comment: While this is certainly an interesting question to pose - I actually have the liberty of restructuring how the data is formed, and it's an incredibly easy fix to bypass having to do this at all. As such, I'll be closing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is certainly an interesting question - I have the liberty to just restructure how the data's scraped, and as such can bypass having to do this at all.

Thanks all!